# CSS: set the whole page opacity

Tags: html, css

i am making my eportfolio and i have a popout box. This is suppose to make the whole screen behind it dim, which it does until you scroll down. Im not sure if you guys know gyazo but here is a gif of what i mean. (its fine if you dont want to click it.)
https://gyazo.com/0513512615ee2e0dd169db12a222a06b

Ok so here is the HTML code

```
<div id="View_Code_Car" class="overlay">
    <div class="Popup">
        <h2>'Car' - Processing Project Code</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
        <div class="Content">
            <img src = "Images/View_Code_Car.png" <img/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transition: opacity 350ms;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

There is more Code for the pop up but it doesnt control the opacity or anything

Comment: Are you talking about a modal dialog?

Comment: i guess it would be classed as a model dialog yeh

Comment: The best thing to do would be to disable overflow(remove the scroll bar) when the modal window is open. You can do this by adding `overflow:hidden;` to the `body`.

Comment: the body of the html? i added it to the .overlay and it didnt do anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to set your modal overlay to `position: fixed;` to it adheres to the window.  `position: absolute;` references itself to the closest parent container set to `position: relative;'.

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transition: opacity 350ms;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
```

You would still be able to scroll the page, but the modal would remain fixed to the window.

Comment: this works but another object is now overlapping it. i think it has something to do with the z index because i have this tab control object which goes in front of everything.

Comment: Correct.  I amended the CSS to include a z-index position.  You will need to inspect your code to determine what this value should be.

Comment: oh i just added z-index:3; on the overlay and it worked. thanks

Comment: No worries.  Don't forget to close out questions by marking correct.